# Permanent of a low-rank matrix is easy to calculate?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, computer-science, computational-complexity, permanent

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3245), Aaronson and Arkhipov use the following lemma (lemma 67 in the paper):

*Let $V \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix of rank $k$. Then $\operatorname{Per}(V + I)$ is computable exactly in $n^{O(k)}$ time.*

Unfortunately, they refer to a "forthcoming paper" which I was unable to find. Is there a publication where this or a similar statement is proven?

Answer (score 4):

Alexander Barvinok gave an algorithm to compute the permanent of a rank $r$ matrix in $O(n^{r-1})$ arithmetic operations; see Theorem 3.3 in:

*Barvinok, Alexander I.*, [**Two algorithmic results for the traveling salesman problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1287/moor.21.1.65), Math. Oper. Res. 21, No. 1, 65-84 (1996). [ZBL0846.90115](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0846.90115).

This is for $\text{Per}(V)$, not $\text{Per}(\text{Id}+V)$. I'm not sure how to put the identity matrix in; the first version of this answer said I could do it, but then I started writing out the details and failed.